# Fact or Fiction? You decide. (Polygon trivia)

Tags: knowledge, rebus

Here is an assertion regarding a certain type of polygon.  Fact or fiction?
You may weigh in, but a correct answer simply decrypts the assertion:

> 001133445566778899
> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ
> 451
> Albert and Edward
> ~2.598076211353316xsxs
> +1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The claim is:

> **No two snowflakes are alike.**

001133445566778899

> **NO TWOS** – 22 is missing from the digit pairs.

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ

> **NO W** – the W is missing from the alphabet.

451

> **F** as in Farenheit. "Fahrenheit 451" is a novel by Ray Bradbury named by the temperature at which paper starts to burn.

Albert and Edward

> These are **LAKES** in Africa linked by the Semliki river.

~2.598076211353316xsxs

> **AREA**. The formula is the area of a hexagon dependent on its side s:
>  A = 3⁄2 √3 · s² ≈ 2.598076211 · s²

+1

> **LIKE** as in the thumbs-up / +1 buttons in social media.